# Vault query in Corda

Tags: corda

I have mapping in schema classes where one policy type can be used by multiple users. One to many relation between policy and users. Created a users table which contain one column which refers to policy id.

I want to write vault query to get policy along with its users.

Note: Policy and Users have different state / schema classes.

Is it possible to write vault query on multiple states.

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely can - you need to create a VaultQueryCriteria that causes the nodes to look for both of the state types.

You do this by passing the VaultQueryCriteria a Set of state classes. I've included an example snippet below with some arbitrary state types (DiceRollState & SettlementState). It's important to note that you need to specify ContractState as the type parameter for the queryBy method (given that all states should subclass ContractState)

`serviceHub.vaultService.queryBy<ContractState>(QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria(contractStateTypes = setOf(DiceRollState::class.java, SettlementState::class.java)))`

Comment: But then do I need to join those states / schemas with `@OneToMany` or `@ManyToOne` mapping?

Comment: Hmmm - you could go with that approach and write a custom schema for both the Policy and User states. What might be easier, however, is to get all the User States from the vault using the query criteria ```QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria(contractStateTypes = setOf(UserState::class.java))``` and then filtering for only users that match the policy.